# JPA : @JoinColunm gives an Error

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, netbeans-7, toplink-essentials

I am trying my hands on the Netbeans E-Coomerce tutorials
  from this [page](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html#whatEJB). It makes use of both JPA and ORM

This is a Java EE project named the Affablebean deployed to the GlasFish server.

As part of the tutorials I created a database model with the MySQL Workbench. Then forward engineered the model to create the database.

THe Netbeans wizard was used to create entity classes from the database tables.And from the entity classes , I created session beans by use of the Netbeans wizard.

But after creating the session beans , Netbeans raises an error when ever I run the Affablebean project.

The error talks about the annotation of the entity class OrderedProduct not complete. I have therefore added the code snippet of the entity class>

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordered_product")
@XmlRootElement

public class OrderedProduct implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private short quantity;

    @JoinColumn(name = "Product_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product product;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Customer_Order_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private CustomerOrder customerOrder;

    public OrderedProduct() {
    }

    public OrderedProduct(OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK) {
        this.orderedProductPK = orderedProductPK;
    }

    public OrderedProduct(OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK, short quantity) {
        this.orderedProductPK = orderedProductPK;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public OrderedProduct(int customerOrderid, int productid) {
        this.orderedProductPK = new OrderedProductPK(customerOrderid, productid);
    }

    public OrderedProductPK getOrderedProductPK() {
        return orderedProductPK;
    }

    public void setOrderedProductPK(OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK) {
        this.orderedProductPK = orderedProductPK;
    }       

}
```

This is the session bean that was created from the entity class:

```
@Stateless
public class OrderedProductFacade extends AbstractFacade<OrderedProduct> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AffableBeanPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public OrderedProductFacade() {
        super(OrderedProduct.class);
    }

}
```

Below is the Error message.

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [AffableBeanPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field customerOrder] from the entity class [class entity.OrderedProduct] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [AffableBeanPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field customerOrder] from the entity class [class entity.OrderedProduct] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [AffableBeanPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field customerOrder] from the entity class [class entity.OrderedProduct] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:221)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field customerOrder] from the entity class [class entity.OrderedProduct] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.incompleteJoinColumnsSpecified(ValidationException.java:1817)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.getJoinColumnsAndValidate(MappingAccessor.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.getJoinColumns(MappingAccessor.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOneToOneForeignKeyRelationship(ObjectAccessor.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOwningMappingKeys(ObjectAccessor.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToOneAccessor.process(ManyToOneAccessor.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1337)
    ... 37 more

SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [AffableBeanPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field customerOrder] from the entity class [class entity.OrderedProduct] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [AffableBeanPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field customerOrder] from the entity class [class entity.OrderedProduct] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field customerOrder] from the entity class [class entity.OrderedProduct] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.incompleteJoinColumnsSpecified(ValidationException.java:1817)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.getJoinColumnsAndValidate(MappingAccessor.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.getJoinColumns(MappingAccessor.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOneToOneForeignKeyRelationship(ObjectAccessor.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOwningMappingKeys(ObjectAccessor.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToOneAccessor.process(ManyToOneAccessor.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1337)
    ... 37 more
```

Any suggestion will be appreiated

Answer (score 0):

What are the ids for CustomerOrder and Product? If they are composite, then you need to include multiple JoinColumns.  If they are single, then you can remove the "referencedColumnName = "id"", which is probably wrong anyway because of the case (try upper case).

Comment: The CustomerOrder entity class uses a composite key that is :          EmbeddedId CustomerOrderPK customerOrderPK;                                                But the Product entity class uses an auto-generated primary key. @James